# Estou tentando enviar um email de contato pelo meu site, mas da o seguinte erro:

Tags: php

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\UwAmp\www\Site\processa.php on line 29

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $email);
        $subject = "Confirmar email";
        $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "fusionrpsuporte@gmail.com");
        $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Olá, Equipe de suporte do Fusion.<br><br>$titulo<br>Nome: $nome<br>Email: $email<br> Mensagem: $mensagem");
        $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

        //Necessário inserir a chave
        $apiKey = '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';
        $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

        $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
        echo $response->statusCode();
        echo $response->headers();
        echo $response->body();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O método `echo $response->headers();` recebe array e não string, logo usar `ECHO` não funciona, use print_r ou var_dump, assim:

```
echo $response->statusCode();
var_dump($response->headers());
echo $response->body();
```